# Дано две стороны треугольника и угол между ними в градусах. Найти длину третьей стороны, периметр и площадь треугольника

Tags: java

Делаю по примеру задачки из интернета, но площадь получается не та как в задаче, почему понять не могу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше вставьте вместо скриншота сам код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите пример корня [тут](http://proglang.su/java/numbers-sqrt) и пример получения косинуса [тут](http://proglang.su/java/numbers-cos). Вы не правильно получаете косинус.
Надо,как указано в примере указанном выше, передавать радианы,а не градусы.

```
  double degrees = 120.0;
  double cos = Math.toRadians(degrees);
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось ;)

Comment: Отметьте,тогда, пожалуйста, что ответ принят

Comment: сугубо в учебных целях стоило бы добавить что `radians = PI/180*degrees;`,